# How to bring Activity to top of stack and reset it?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to keep my activity calling flow simple for the user.  Always one instance of the activity on the history stack.

So using flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT), is perfect! but there is a slight issue.

The activity is brought to the front and the onCreate() is not called if already started. Makes sense but I want the behavior to be that it calls onCreate().

Thanks for the help!

-Jona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you are searching for is the method onNewIntent(). This method should be called if your Activity is already in the stack and is started again.

In here the new Intent should be passed to you, so that you can react and initialize you variables like you would do in onCreate() with the intent data fetched via getIntent().

Comment: How would you clear the intent after consumption on the activity? I have tried setIntent(null) but it didn't seem like it actually cleared the original intent. I want to do this since after flipping the orientation the onCreate() returns the last passed intent...